# Queen bee syndrome in academia

Tags: advisor, supervision, reference-request

The queen bee syndrome was first defined by social psychologists in the 70s, describing a behaviour of women in advanced positions in traditionally male-dominated areas that in part means that they treat female subordinates more harshly and critically than men and may even impede the advancement of these female subordinates.

In the context of male dominated areas of academia, how prevalent the "queen bee syndrome" in the relationship between female graduate supervisors and their female graduate students? Does the literature and research in social psychology, management, organisational behaviour and education confirm this phenomenon?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate what kind of an answer you are looking for. For example, this could be an overview of scientific studies (if any exist) or personal experiences. The latter is not a suitable question for this site as it is a survey and answers cannot be evaluated.

Comment: The only "answer" I could give here would be _frame breaking_, so I'll desist. But I don't see how the data could be interpreted. Is a female supervisor who pushes her students especially hard (carrot and stick) because she thinks, possibly correctly, that her female students will be judged _by others_ extremely harshly fit the definition of a Queen Bee? Or is she just a Shepherd watching diligently over her flock?  I think that is a much more likely thing to see than someone whose world view is "none of you will ever be as good as I am and I'll do what I can to ensure that."

Comment: I'm talking about the difference between how male and female graduate students are treated and thought of by a female supervisor.

Comment: Why do you think there is a difference? Personal experience or something else?

Comment: Personal experience and then I found this term which seems to have been studied in a few areas and reflects my situation.

Comment: I think a question more specific to your own situation might be more welcome here than one that seeks to apply a possible general idea. Perhaps you just have a bad supervisor and need guidance on that. I suspect that women can be as bad as men as supervisors. A lot of questions here deal with how to deal with poor supervision - even hostile supervisors.

Comment: This is actually a term that has been actively researched, so I don't see how it is opinion based- I'm asking for someone's understanding of the literature.

Comment: A simple Google Scholar search for "queen bee academia" turned up a number of relevant results, including a recent paper [Faniko et al (2020)](https://bpspsychub.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/bjso.12408) that seems to address exactly the question you have.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been closed as opinion-based; the question asks for literature and it is easy to give literature that examines the exact question at issue.

Comment: @Ben I agree and have voted to reopen. I think this question was closed out of concern answers might state opinions and conjectures (see comments) rather than refer to existing sources.

Comment: @henning: Yeah, okay, I've also voted to re-open.  Lit search suggests there are some papers on this, so I'm sure we can give a decent objective answer that is not just opinion.

Comment: I think the idea that we should close questions on this site that do not allow objective answers is essentially just Stack Exchange dogma: in reality, what keeps a question open on this site is the need it expresses for one or more academics to weigh in with their *professionally relevant opinions and experiences*.   This question actually seems harder to answer: indeed the term **Queen Bee Syndrome** (which does not ring so nicely in my ear, FWIW) exists in the social science literature.  Is the OP asking for a compilation or evaluation of this research?  This site is not really for that...

Answer (score 6):

Since you have not mentioned any recent papers, I'm going to assume that you are stuck finding papers on this topic.  A simple Google Scholar search for "queen bee academia" turns up a number of relevant results, including [Ellemers et al (2004)](https://bpspsychub.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1348/0144666042037999) and [Faniko et al (2020)](https://bpspsychub.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/bjso.12408), which both seem to address the phenomenon of interest to you.  Now, obviously you will need to do a bigger literature review than this, but those two papers should give you a place to get started, and they will lead you to other references.